# Python CSV: Replace cell value (float) of row with new value (float)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

**updated** Sample CSV Data:

```
c1,c2,v1,v2,p1,p2,r1,a1,f1,f2,f3,Time_Stamp 

0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:00
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:01
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:02
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:03
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:04
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:05
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:06
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:07
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:08
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:09
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:10
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:11
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:12
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:13
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:14
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:15
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:16 
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:17
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:18
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:19
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:20
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:21
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:22
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:23
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:24
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:25
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:26
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:27
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:28
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:29
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:30
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:31
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:32
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:33
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:34
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:35
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:36
```

**Edited**- Reading of CSV, Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date,time,datetime
import pandas as pd

def readcsv(x): #def function to read csv files based on input below
    Data = pd.read_csv(x, parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    Data['Date'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.date #creating Date Column in the Data Frame ( does not affect the main .csv file)
    Data['Time'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.time #creating Time Column in the Data Frame ( also does not affect the main .csv file)
    #print (Data) #<-- prints the output
    #print (Data['Time_Stamp'][6000:7000]) <- print from row 6000 to 7000 of the data frame (has over 150'000 rows)
    Data['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Time_Stamp']) # Time_Stamp Data Frame
    print(Data[1:6])
    return Data

Data = readcsv('data.csv')


#Data = csv file data 

def getMask(start,end,Data):
    mask = (Data['Time_Stamp'] > start) & (Data['Time_Stamp'] <= end)
    return mask;

start = '2017-06-13 16:00:00'
end = '2017-06-13 16:40:00'
timerange = Data.loc[getMask(start, end, Data)]

pspike = timerange.loc[timerange['c1'] <= 5.0]
```

**pspike output:**

***the row*** : for e.g. -> After printing `pspike` , the printed row has `time` value of `16:38:15` and the next printed row has `time` value of `16:38:17`, that means it skipped a row where the time value is `16:38:16`

[ e.g. below ]

```
13/06/2017 16:38:12
13/06/2017 16:38:13
13/06/2017 16:38:14
13/06/2017 16:38:15
13/06/2017 16:38:17
13/06/2017 16:38:18
```

After running the code below, it prints out the row( only the Time_Stamp value ) that was skipped, which has `time` value of `16:38:16`, `16:38:22` and `16:38:32` where the rows with that value were skipped based on the output of `pspike`

```
for i in range(timerange.shape[0] - 1):
row1 = timerange.iloc[i]
row2 = timerange.iloc[i+1]
if (row2[-1] - row1[-1]).seconds > 1:
    print (row1[-1] + pd.Timedelta('1s'))
```

Output:

```
2017-06-13 16:38:16
2017-06-13 16:38:22
2017-06-13 16:38:32
```

What I'm trying to get is to print the whole row where the `Time_Stamp` value is `2017-06-13 16:38:16`, where its the only row with **`c1`** value that is more than **5.0**, in this case (based on the sample code), its `415.7`

Instead of this:

```
13/06/2017 16:38:16
```

I want to print it like this:

```
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:16
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:22
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:32
```

After printing that row out, I have to replace the value of **`c1`** - `415.7` directly above, with `0.0` . How do I do this?

**EDIT**

**What to replace:**

The `c1` of the missing row in **pspike output**

Comment: Can you simplify your problem statement? What are all the values you want to replace with 0? Basically, what is the condition for replacement.

Comment: What is the column "AC_Input_Current"? I cannot see that in the data

Comment: My bad, I've edited and changed it to what it suppose to be , which is `c1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused here because you could simply do:

```
pspike = timerange[timerange['c1'].gt(5.0)] #gr=greater than, lt=lower than
```

---

Which returns a dataframe with:

```
16  415.7   12.5    30.2    154.6   4675.2  1   -1  5199.4  0   50  0   2017-06-13 16:38:16
```

Set values of column "c1" to 0.0

```
pspike["c1"] = 0.0
```

Create a string from first row (index=0):

```
','.join(pspike.astype(str).values.tolist()[0])
```

Prints:

```
'0.0,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,2017-06-13 16:38:16'
```

---

**Update**

```
string = """c1,c2,v1,v2,p1,p2,r1,a1,f1,f2,f3,Time_Stamp
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:00
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:01
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:02
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:03
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:04
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:05
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:06
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:07
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:08
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:09
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:10
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:11
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:12
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:13
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:14
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:15
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:16 
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:17
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:18
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:19
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:20
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:21
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:22
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:23
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:24
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:25
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:26
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:27
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:28
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:29
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:30
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:31
415.7,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:32
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:33
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:34
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:35
0,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,941.0,0,50,0,13/06/2017 16:38:36"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string)) # reads data from string above
#Use : df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')  for csv file (handling tons of data)
df["Time_Stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time_Stamp"]) # convert to Datetime
df_filter = df[df["c1"].le(0.5)] # new df with less or equal to 0.5
where = (df_filter[df_filter["Time_Stamp"].diff().dt.total_seconds() > 1] ["Time_Stamp"] - pd.Timedelta("1s")).astype(str).tolist() # Find where diff > 1 second
df_filter2 = df[df["Time_Stamp"].isin(where)] # Create new df with those
df_filter2["c1"] = 0.0 # Set c1 to 0.0

for index, row in df_filter2.iterrows():
    values = row.astype(str).tolist()
    print(','.join(values))
```

Return

```
0.0,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,2017-06-13 16:38:16
0.0,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,2017-06-13 16:38:22
0.0,12.5,30.2,154.6,4675.2,1,-1,5199.4,0,50,0,2017-06-13 16:38:32
```

Comment: Based on the sample data I provided, getting **only** the row with value of `c1` greater than 5.0 would be easier if to go with your method. But the actual data can have repeated rows with `c1` values more than 5.0 

I want to get the rows where `c1` is lesser than 5.0 **And** if the printed row has skipped 1 second in the `time` value of the `Time_Stamp, then that row that was skipped is the specific row that I want to edit the value of `c1` to 0.0

Comment: @SanctaIgnis But wouldn't it make sense to handle those instead?

Comment: I tried the updated codes but it only printed the column names and not the values, any idea why?

Comment: @SanctaIgnis Actually no idea why - tried it myself and it did work for me(but those are just the initial steps). I don't feel like the code is super safe though. I'd say you would have to provide a larger data sample and explain the expected output when there are multiple values.

Comment: I edited and added little more data and the expected output

Comment: @SanctaIgnis Check my updated example with your data.

Comment: Since the output of what I wanted is in another dataframe - `df_filter2` , is there a way where I can put it back into the first `df`, replacing its previous row with the same Time_Stamp with the rows in `df_filter2`

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain a little more on this line `where = (df_filter[df_filter["Time_Stamp"].diff().dt.total_seconds() > 1] ["Time_Stamp"] - pd.Timedelta("1s")).astype(str).tolist() # Find where diff > 1 second`,

Comment: I seem to notice that I have different `Time_Stamp` value Output if I were to reduce the number of data within a certain `Time_Stamp` range. *Note:* For e.g. my .csv file that I read into the `df` has over 150,000 rows, after running the code above, I manage to see a row with `Time_Stamp` of `2017-06-13 16:15:21` in the **Output**. So I went to check if this is right, I went to make `df` values where it has `Time_Stamp` from `2017-06-13 16:15:00` to `2017-06-13 16:15:59`, to see if it prints `16:15:21` as well...but it didn't print. Is it my misunderstanding of your codes ?

Comment: @SanctaIgnis An idea that comes to mind is to look at the difference and if it is 35 (we create an array of those 35 values).

Comment: I'm still confused and not sure what is the `difference` you are referring to

Comment: @SanctaIgnis Can you figure out how to isolate the problem and share it / or share the whole file?